# Disable incoming emails for a specific virtual user

Tags: linux, postfix

I've just setup a mail server with mysql virtual users.
I want to use an account for sending notifications/registrations emails from my website

I found no options for disabling incoming emails, so my first thing is to set the user quota to 0.

Tried to send a mail and I got:

```
Mar 28 19:24:23 mail postfix/smtpd[4977]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-wg0-f42.google.com[74.125.82.42]: 450 4.7.1 <notifications@mysite.net>: Recipient address rejected: Policy Rejection- Please try later.; from=<someone@gmail.com> to=<notifications@mysite.net> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-wg0-f42.google.com>
Mar 28 19:24:23 mail postfix/smtpd[4977]: disconnect from mail-wg0-f42.google.com[74.125.82.42]
```

Seems to work but the message is `Policy Rejection- Please try later.`

It's the right way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reject a specific e-mail address/account do the following:

first have a look at your main.cf

look for

> smtpd_recipient_restrictions

add

> check_recipient_access hash:/opt/local/etc/postfix/filtered_domains

to the list of options

in my case the configuration parameter would look like the following:

> smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
>           permit_mynetworks,
>           permit_sasl_authenticated,
>           reject_unlisted_recipient,
>           reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
>           reject_unauth_destination,
>           reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
>           check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/filtered_domains

then edit /etc/postfix/filtered_domains for your needs
for example :

> user@myexample.com REJECT
> anotheruser@virtualdomain.org REJECT

then build the table for postfix

> postmap filtered_domains

You are done. 
user@myexample.com and anotheruser@virtualdomain.org are now beeing rejected. So there's no need to set the user quota to zero anymore.

As you use MySQL virtual tables it would be easy to change your virtual users table. For example add a flag 'disabled' and change the table format for filtered_domains to mysql, and define the according query which delivers the appropriate email address when the 'disabled' flag is set.

Comment: Nice. Now I got a reply that said `The error that the other server returned was:
554 5.7.1 <notifications@mysite.net>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied`. This is not the case of quota turned to 0

Comment: how about rejecting for an entire domain?